# Play store says my app is supported by 0 devices - no devices are compatible with my app

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play

I have recently finished building my first android app. I published it to the store today but it says it supports 0 devices. Here is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.guessthepicturespazam.guessit" >

    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="נחש את המילה"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="נחש את המילה"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".GameActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_game"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="נחש את המילה"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".StoreActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_store" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".GameOverActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_game_over" >
        </activity>
    </application>
    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true" />
    </manifest>
```

This is my build.grade file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.GuessTheWordZahal.guessit"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.8.0'
}
```

I tried looking this problem up online but I couldn't find a problem similar to mine. Most apps have no supported devices because they use features that are only available in some or in no devices. I just can't figure out what's wrong in mine. I've actually tested this app on my samsung galaxy and it worked fine

Comment: remove: <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true" />

Comment: I actually added that only after finding out about the problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this same problem, what fixed it for me was changing

```
compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
```

in build.gradle to

```
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
```